# Testing gasprice

Tags: ethereum, solidity, truffle

I am playing with the ability of being able to set the maximum gasPrice that a transaction can broadcast to be accepted. Checked with the following:

```
require(tx.gasprice <= gasPriceLimit * 1000000000);
```

And then calling the following from my test script:

```
await contract.mint({gasprice: txnGasPrice});
```

The expected fails are not happening because ganache have default tx.gasprice it uses.. how can I make sure my test gasprice is used instead?

Thanks
A.

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime, I have got around it by setting a gasprice in truffle.js and then playing with the gasPriceLimit.